# tween three js start from part

Tags: three.js, tween

I have TWEEN

```
rotate = new TWEEN.Tween({ vertical:min  }).to({ vertical:max },3000000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).start()
```

And I want to start from half, or another part. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: rotate = new TWEEN.Tween({ vertical:(min+max)/2  }).to({ vertical:max },3000000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).start()

Comment: usually tween is much more complicated than this most simple example. this is not start from half but start from zero with shorter duration. That means different result in easing. This is the reason why I m asking.

Comment: ok considering delay and duration: rotate = new TWEEN.Tween({ vertical:min }).to({ vertical:max },1500000).delay(1500000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).start()

Comment: delay will make tween delayed before start, if i do this, tween will half time wait and half time run. If there will be any other easing than linear, the tween curve will be shorter.

Comment: to be clear i updated question with image